# Does WPF Work with C++?

Tags: c++, wpf, visual-studio

My understanding is that Microsoft Visual Studio was rewritten to use WPF. I'm still not clear on why, but acknowledge my knowledge about WPF is very limited.

My question is if anyone knows how much support WPF has for C++, and if Visual Studio is still written in C++.

Personally, WPF primarily appears to be .NET/VB/C# thing. Is anyone using it with C++?

Comment: Are you asking about WPF + C++ *in general*, or about its use in Visual Studio specifically?

Comment: There were actually two question there. One had to do with using WPF with C++. The other had to do with the language used to write Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio does indeed use WPF as part of it's UI in the 2010 release.  Large portions of Visual Studio are also still written in C++.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use WPF with C++/CLI.  It is a .NET API, however, so it requires the .NET Framework.

That being said, the designer support is non-existent with C++.  This means that, for practical purposes, WPF doesn't really work with C++.

Typically, the user interface layer is written in C# (or VB.NET), then calls into C++ code, often exposed via P/Invoke or C++/CLI layers.  By using C++/CLI, it's very easy to interoperate between C++ code and C#/VB.NET code.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much what I was thinking. But that made me wonder why VS would be rewritten for WPF. I ask because I do quite a bit of C# these days and am wondering if I should choose WPF instead of MFC, which I've used in the past.

Comment: @Jonathan: If you're using C#, I'd really look hard at WPF.  It's far superior in many ways... I wrote a series on migrating to WPF from Windows Forms - while it's not MFC, the same concepts apply.  It would give you a good idea of some of the benefits to WPF: http://reedcopsey.com/talks/from-windows-forms-to-wpf-with-mvvm/

Comment: My past experience has been C++/MFC for the desktop and C#/WebForms for the web. So I haven't spent too much time with WinForms. But since most of my recent development has been for the web, I'm becoming increasing comfortable with C#. I'll take a look at your link.

Comment: @Jonathan: It'll make sense from a MFC point of view, and most of it applies to Silverlight, as well.  Should be useful if you want to consider the switch to WPF or Silverlight, for Desktop or Web...

Comment: Did anything changed now? I'd love to use this  GUI in C++ in a native executable.

Answer (score 19):

WPF is a .NET technology. Of course it *can* be used with C++, like any other part of .NET can, but it requires you to jump through some interop hoops, or possibly write it all in C++/CLI. (And you'll have to write a lot of boilerplate code yourself, as the designer doesn't work with C++/CLI.)

And Visual Studio isn't, and probably never was, "written in C++". With 2010, members of the VS team have stated on their blogs that VS is now primarily a managed application. Of course there's still a ton of C++ code in there, and that's not going away any time soon, but a lot of it is C#/VB today.

But that didn't happen overnight. Managed code has gradually been added to Visual Studio with every release. Visual Studio is written in many different languages.

If what you're actually asking is "can I write an addin for Visual Studio using C++", then the answer is "yes".

If you're asking "is it practical to write an application in C++, and still use WPF", the answer is probably "only if you write the WPF code in C#, and then have some interop code binding this together with your C++ app.

Comment: That's interesting that the developers are saying VS 2010 is now primarily managed code. I wish I had a better picture of how much is managed and why. I mostly ask because I've done a lot of MFC in the past and am wondering if it makes sense to move to C#, which I use a lot lately, and WPF.

Comment: @Jonathan: for UI work, I'd definitely prefer WPF (probably with C#/VB) over anything else Microsoft has produced. And for most purposes, C# is a very good language, so it *might* make sense to use it for more than just the UI.

Comment: I was wondering why Visual Studio started loading and working so slow after 2008 version. Now I know the answer...

Comment: Btw, managed doesn't mean that they use C#. It might be that they use C++ with CLR/CLI.

Comment: @Lilian A. Moraru: I can't feel it. Also, still loading faster than any Java program ever written.

Answer (score 3):

Noesis gui can run WPF UIs in c++. You will have to adapt the c# classes to c++ (using their reflection macros, etc). Some controls aren't supported, but it is quite elegant.

For example, WPF might generate :

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace BlendTutorial
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ContainerBorder_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you would convert it to c++ :

```
namespace BlendTutorial
{

class MainWindow final: public Window
{
public:
    MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private:
    void InitializeComponent()
    {
        Noesis::GUI::LoadComponent(this, "MainWindow.xaml");
    }

    bool ConnectEvent(BaseComponent* source, const char* event, const char* handler) override
    {
        NS_CONNECT_EVENT(Button, Click, AddButton_Click);
        NS_CONNECT_EVENT(Button, Click, RemoveButton_Click);
        NS_CONNECT_EVENT(Border, PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, ContainerBorder_MouseDown);
        NS_CONNECT_ATTACHED_EVENT(ToggleButton, Checked, RadioButton_Checked);
        return false;
    }

    void AddButton_Click(BaseComponent*, const RoutedEventArgs&)
    {
    }

    void RemoveButton_Click(BaseComponent*, const RoutedEventArgs&)
    {
    }

    void ContainerBorder_MouseDown(BaseComponent*, const MouseButtonEventArgs&)
    {
    }

    void RadioButton_Checked(BaseComponent*, const RoutedEventArgs&)
    {
    }

    NS_IMPLEMENT_INLINE_REFLECTION(MainWindow, Window)
    {
        NsMeta<TypeId>("BlendTutorial.MainWindow");
    }
};
```

More info here : https://www.noesisengine.com/docs/Gui.Core.BlendTutorial.html

They have some pretty nifty stuff if you want to go ham with data models, bindings and mvvp. Or you can just hook up lambdas to control events.

It is a paid framework, though it's free for less than €100K yearly income.