# Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2012 using XAML

Tags: c++, xaml, user-interface

I am trying to write my first GUI using XAML for Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012. XAML isn't listed as a template anywhere and I can't find anywhere to install it.

If you could help me set up my first project I will be grateful!

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my answer, I didn't see that you wanted C++. I'm under the impression that the C++/XAML combo is only for Windows Store applications (Windows 8)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly I don't think there is support(atleast no official support) for XAML together with C++ except for in [Windows 8 Store apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/08/24/10343401.aspx).

There is a discussion about bringing XAML to C++ desktop apps, which can be found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/9ae97df8-0bb1-40f0-bd4a-688a1c3b47a3/

Also this question might be intresting for you, which is about using [WPF with C++.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776355/does-wpf-work-with-c)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Johan Falk's response, you could create a C# project and use that as your front-end GUI and do any of your back-end logic in a separate C++ project in the same solution.