# WPF GUI Creator

Tags: c++, wpf

I would like to ask you if anyone knows whether MS is willing to let GUI creation for WPF for other languages, in a practical way, like for example in C++. Is the upcoming WPF version adding new features on this topic?

Thanks

Comment: WPF is a .net framework and so you should be able to use it from any language that targets the CLR including managed C++. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776355/does-wpf-work-with-c

Answer (score 2):

Well, the simple answer is that WPF is a managed UI framework, so can be used from any managed (.NET) language, such as VB.NET, C#, C++/CLI (managed C++), F#, IronRuby, IronPython, etc.  It may not be terribly useable in managed C++ though.  The best language for most WPF programming is the declarative XAML language, and tools like Expression Blend for generating it.