# Creating a fully functional MP3 player in Windows

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, mfc

How do i create a MP3 player for windows? I need a good GUI.
My main question is:

1. Which is better Win32 API, QT, MFC, or anything else ?
2. I am good in Java, but i cannot develop this project in Java as the project specs says. Other than Java i do know C++. Now, which one should i use to get my work done quickly, i.e MFC, Win32 API or Qt?
3. Please provide links to the websites where i can learn the thing that you say is better.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Neither one of MFC, QT or Win32 is a programming language. Perhaps you meant C? (And no, you can't learn C in a week so that you can start out with a new project...)

Comment: I already know C++ and i was asking related to that, i.e. VS C++ or MFC or Qt. Which is better ?? Or can i do the coding in VS and then add the GUI in Qt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  you want a good looking GUI in Windows, and you're familiar with Java, a reasonable route to go would be to use WPF.  You can make a really fancy looking UI, and you can do all the actual logic in C#, which is similar enough to Java that you shouldn't have too much trouble learning it.

Comment: Can i use the WPF with C++? As i already know C++ and plan to develop the app on that. And WPF works with Visual Studio 2012, right?

Comment: While you can use WPF with C++, it's not the easy way around.  See here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776355/does-wpf-work-with-c  WPF most certainly does work with VS2012.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon !! I am out of the dilemma.